# Why is http + swagger trigger missing?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am working in Logic App Standard.  Built-in connectors include support triggering via swagger doc as described [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http-swagger)

When I open the portal and select swagger, nothing shows up. When I enter http, no options for HTTP + Swagger are offered.  I do see it offered as an Action.

Looking around on the web, there's no indication that this connector is not supported on standard edition.  Any ideas on what to look for to enable support?

Here is my portal view selecting http

[image]

Comment: The documentation you are pointing at is for logic app on consumption plan not for logic app standard.

Answer (score 1):

***I have reproduced in my environment and I do agree with @Thomas, Http + Swagger Trigger is only found in Consumption Plan of Logic app as below:***

[image]

***Whereas in Standard Plan of Logic App we cannot see it as below:***

[image]